# Google Playstore "You need to check that your screenshot image is a valid image."

Tags: android, google-play

I know that the image has to be no more than a 2:1 aspect ratio and should either have no alpha, or be a jpeg. The pictures I'm using satisfies these criteria but I still am getting the error message.

[One of the image in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzAMb.jpg)

Comment: I wonder if this is a programming questions?

Comment: I agree with Xenolion. It is not a programming question. Dear @winnie please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic. A much better contact for this question would be Play Console support.